# Choppy jQuery Scrolling in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a small snippet of jQuery that I'm using to move my nav bar when the user scrolls then have it stick 75px from the top of the page.

In IE9 the scrolling is super smooth, but in Firefox it's very jerky and choppy.

Here's my code:

jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('div.hnav').css('margin-top',Math.max(-235,0-scrollTop));
});
```

css:

```
div.hnav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 300px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a [throttle function](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) so that code isn't executed every 2ms when scrolling

Comment: I got suggestion... I will probably get killed by saying that, but... Change browser to something less buggy, as FF is more buggy novadays than IE.

Comment: alright getting @FlashThunder's voodoo doll out

Comment: Why not just update the CSS value of `top` when your scroll condition is met e.g. `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) { $('div.hnav').css('top', 75) }`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, could you please elaborate further? I'm unfamiliar with setting up a throttle function. Thanks!

Comment: gvee - thank for the suggestion, I'll give that a try, but I'm not sure if it will give me the desired effect. Cheers.

Comment: @FlashThunder a visitor isn't going to give two bits of a shart which web browser is better. It needs to work in the web browser which they are using or else they do not return.

Comment: Ok, that depends of situation. I for example tell my clients that my projects wont work on shitty browsers, and if they don't agree, they may resign. But it is different situation, as I see.

Comment: @FlashThunder so you create an e-commerce site and get > 10k visitors a month and tell people using any version of FF to GTFO? I wouldn't hire you in a heartbeat...

Comment: Not every web project is public.

Comment: So why set yourself up to get intimidated by public projects or embarrassment when you attempt them

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `margin-top`.   Changing the margin values often causes reflow.  Why not just use `top`, as you've already got that set up to be positioned anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I've found often the solution is to let the scrolling be handled by the GPU.  One way you can force this to happen is by adding

```
webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
```

to the element you are scrolling. You can see what is being handled by the GPU vs CPU by opening the page in Chrome->Developer Tools->General and selecting "Force accelerated compisiting" and "Show composited layer borders".  That will cause an orange border to appear around anything being handled by the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this approach instead: **http://jsfiddle.net/Uxn9f/**

### Updated CSS

```
div.hnav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Swapped from `fixed` to `absolute` positioning. This allows the element to move with the scroll of the page.

### Changed JQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 235) {
        $('div.hnav').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': 75
        })
    } else {
        $('div.hnav').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 300
        })
    }
});
```

Essentially what we're doing is checking the current scroll of the page. When we reach a certain point (235px) we will "lock" the `.hnav` to be 75px from the top of the viewport by changing its positioning (type and dimension).

If the user scrolls back up past out magic 235px mark, reset the positioning.

Comment: Thanks. Smooth until it gets to the end. Then there is a very noticeable snap from absolute to fixed position in Firefox, I don't see the snap in IE9.

Comment: Hey @Bryan, I think the "snap" is because the math is slightly off in my above code. Change the 235 to 225 (300 - 75)